# equivalent way to run pig UDF with external file of oozie workflow file element

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a oozie workflow with mainly pig jobs.

In the `workflow.xml` there is one line `<file>${hdfsPath}/hdfsLineItem.txt#LineItem.txt</file>`

This file is used in one of UDFs, which is indirectly used by other UDF, the source code snippet is `in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("./LineItem.txt"));`

I don't have permission to submit oozie job but I could submit pig jobs.
However I can't find the equivalent way to submit the pig job with that external text file.

I copied that file to my space and run `pig myscript.pig -file LineItem.txt` but the UDF will throw `IOException`. Does anyone know the equivalent way to submit a pig job?

Answer (score 0):

solve my problem by another way. The text file is stored on hdfs as well, I modified the UDF and change it to

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(UDFContext.getUDFContext().getJobConf());
DataInputStream in = new fs.open(new Path("_hdfsPath_/hdfsLineItem.txt"));
```

and the rest of the code are the same. Finally I could submit my pig job directly.